# Docker: Can't connect to mysql under container with docker-compose parameters

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run mysql under container with mysql parameters i defined on docker-compose.yml file. But i have an access denied when i run :
mysql -utest -ptest

I'm only able to connect with mysql -uroot -proot.
Help me please.
Thanks.

```
mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_DATABASE: app
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
        MYSQL_USER: test
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
```

Comment: Add full docker-compose.yaml also paste here error which is thrown when rejecting connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to launch with specified database name like this:

`mysql -u test -p test app`

Explanation:

> MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD
>   These variables are optional, used in conjunction to create a new user and to set that user's password. This user will be granted superuser permissions (see above) for the database specified by the MYSQL_DATABASE variable. Both variables are required for a user to be created.

From MySQL docker hub page

Permissions are granted only for the database specified by environment variable. When you try to log into default database you have no permissions to it only for app database.

Comment: I have access denied too.

Comment: How are you trying to launch this command, from the local host or by docker exec or docker-compose exec?

Comment: Try with `docker-compose exec mysql "mysql -u test -p test app"`

Comment: This working thanks ! Effectively i launched this command with docker and not docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

My complete docker-compose file.

```html
version: '3.2'
services:
    apache:
        container_name: apache
        build: .docker/apache/
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html/app/
        ports:
            - 80:80
        depends_on:
            - php
            - mysql
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
    php:
        container_name: php
        build: .docker/php/
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html/app/
        working_dir: /var/www/html/app/

    mysql:
        container_name: mysql
        image: mysql
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - .docker/data/db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: app
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
            MYSQL_USER: test
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: test
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try attaching an interactive bash process to the already running container by following these steps:

- Get your container id or name from running `docker container ls` in your terminal (I'm talking about the mysql container, which should have the `mysql` name according to your docker-compose.yml file)
- Run `docker exec -it mysql bash` to associate an interactive bash process to the running container
- Now, being inside of your container's filesystem, run `mysql --user=test --password=test` and you should be able to get on with your work